# fseek a newly created file

Tags: c, file, fseek

I have a question about the fseek() usage in C. I know it can set the offset position of a file descriptor created by fopen(). But can it also set the offset position of a newly created file? To be more specific, can I:

```
  FILE * pFile;
  pFile = fopen ( "myfile.txt" , "wb" );  //myfile.txt doesn't exit before
  fseek ( pFile , 1024*1024*1024 , SEEK_SET);
  fclose(pFile);
```

Will it create a file with 1 GB size and no content? Or should I at least write something in order to create this 1 GB file?

Comment: I am reasonably certain that there will be content it will just be random content as in what ever happens to be in the disk area allocated. You may want to initialize the data area to some known value.

Comment: However http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fseek.html says that "The fseek() function shall allow the file-position indicator to be set beyond the end of existing data in the file. If data is later written at this point, subsequent reads of data in the gap shall return bytes with the value 0 until data is actually written into the gap." however what happens if you close the file then open it again? Would it still remember?

Comment: The seek will just move the position, but will not extend the file unless you write something at that position.

Comment: As @MarioZannone said. On a side note, better use `fseeko()` when you want to handle really large files.

Comment: `fseek` may allow seeking beyond the end of the file, but there is nothing that states explicitly whether the file size is extended as a result. [`lseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lseek.html) explicitly states that seeking by itself will not extend the size of the file. In other words, you'd need some form of write operation to extend the size of the file when using `lseek`. However, nothing forbids or allows `fseek` to behave the same way. C11 draft N1570 states, "If a read or write error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and `fseek` fails."

Comment: Why don't you try it? Downvote for no research effort.

Comment: @MarioZannone Thx. I also think I should write something. I will have a try.

Comment: @WeatherVane Since today is Sunday, I just want to ask this question first  to get a general idea before I try it tomorrow :)

Comment: It would have been less effort (since it is Sunday) to try it first.

Comment: @RichardChambers: This can actually be very useful, if the filesystems supports sparse files and you intend to write only some chunks. Initializing would a) cost time and b) allocates all space on storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek

> POSIX allows seeking beyond the existing end of file. If an output is
>   performed after this seek, any read from the gap will return zero
>   bytes. Where supported by the filesystem, this creates a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).

Answer (score 1):

you can do this, it create gap file. any read from gap return zero bytes. system do optimize for file system.